# Visual studio 2013 to compile strict c++11

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

As cited [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) Visual c++ 2013 supports most of c++11, plus some extra features and some changes. However, I need to be able to write and compile strictly in c++11. Is there a package that only contains c++11 headers or some other setting that I can implement to make visual studio work in c++11? I have looked at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx) link question but it isn't exactly what I want. Also I do not have an older version to change the framework to as suggested. Thank you.

Comment: There's no way to select what language version you want to use. Once you select a platform toolset version you get everything that that version supports, be it C++11 or beyond. Maybe you can compile your code with g++ (MinGW) for verification using the `-std=c++11` option. That'll also help you find other non-compliant code that VS accepts.

Comment: @Praetorian is that a modification I can do inside of Visual Studio or do I need to run it in a Linux box and just make my own make file with that flag? This might be off topic and if it is I apologize.

Comment: No, you can't use it from within VS, but you can run it on Windows. Download a MinGW distribution, [one of these](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/) for instance. You'll probably want to use a make file or some other build system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Compliance to `C++11` isn't just a matter of headers. It requires a fully-compliant compiler. If you use `VS2013`, you'll need to settle for the supported subset of `C++11` features.